# Is finding the maximum of a polynomial of degree one a linear programming problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is the following problem expressible as a linear program
\begin{align}
\textbf{P1} \\
\mathrm{maximize} \; \; \; &\left[\left(a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y\right)_+ - \left(c_1x+c_2y\right)\right]_+ - \left(c_1x+c_2y\right) +  \left[\left(\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v,\beta_1u+\beta_2v\right)_+ - \left(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v\right)\right]_+ - \left(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v\right)  \\ 
\text{subject to} \\\;\;\;& 0 \le x,y,u,v \le 1
\end{align}
where $(a,b)_+=\max(a,b)$, $(a)_+=\max(a,0)$, and all the constants are nonnegative.

I'm new to linear programming.
The previous problem appeared in my work, and I don't really know how to solve it.

Since, the polynomial is of degree one, I guess it is possible to convert the $(\cdot)_+$ into constraints.

**Edit**
Is the above problem equivalent to this one
\begin{align}
\textbf{P2}\\
\mathrm{maximize} \;\;\; &p_0 -  \left(c_1x+c_2y\right) + q_0 - \left(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v\right) \\
\text{subject to} \\
\;\;\; &p_0 \ge 0 \\
\;\;\; &p_0 \ge p_1 - \left(c_1x+c_2y\right) \\
\;\;\; &p_1 \ge a_1x+a_2y \\
\;\;\; &p_1 \ge b_1x+b_2y \\
\;\;\; &\text{similarly for } q_0, q_1
\end{align}

I ask because Michael said that P1 is not an LP.
But P2 looks like an LP.
What am I missing?
As I see it, any combination of $\max$ or $\min$ in the objective function can be 'linearized' like in P2.

Comment: If this were actually a *minimization*, I would say that it is, indeed, a linear program. But in fact, because it is a  *maximization*, it is not. It cannot be expressed as an LP (at least not without some binary constraints.) Each branch of the maximums would have to be explored separately. As stated, this problem is actually trivial to solve, though by considering each branch of the maximums.

Comment: If it's a minimization, edit your question and let me know. I have an answer already written for that case---but I deleted it once I realized that I had mis-read it.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant I think, the 'max' in the problem can be 'linearized' so that the problem becomes an LP (see edit). Is it true?

Comment: It depends on whether the outer model is a minimization or a maximization. If you are maximizing, then no, you cannot linearize---the equivalent problem you have offered is *not* correct. If you are minimizing, then yes, you can do this.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant I see that my proposed equivalent is wrong. Can you indicate how to get, or if possible write as an answer, the equivalent problem using binary constraints? I tried to find my way with google, but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective is a piecewise linear convex function, and maximization of such cannot be expressed as a linear program. We can, however, use binary variables to accomplish this.

Let me point out that you can break your model apart into the $x,y$ variables and $u,v$ variables, because they are not coupled. Furthermore, the small size of the problem means that you could in theory just enumerate the vertices $x,y,u,v\in\{0,1\}$ and try them all. Thanks to the decoupling, that's just 4 tests for $x,y$, and 4 tests for $u,v$. So there's really no point in going through all the trouble to convert this problem into a mixed-integer problem, which we're about to do. I am going to do so anyway, however, in case this is actually just a simplification of a more complex model.

First of all, let's do some simplification. Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\max\left\{\max\left\{a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y\right\}-(c_1x+c_2y),0\right\} \\
&\qquad=\max\left\{\max\left\{a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y\right\},c_1x+c_2y\right\}-(c_1x+c_2y) \\
&\qquad=\max\{a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y,c_1x+c_2y\}-(c_1x+c_2y)
\end{aligned}
$$
If we repeat this process for the other term, and insert the result into your model, we get this:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} &\max\{a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y,c_1x+c_2y\}-2(c_1x+c_2y) \\ & + \max\{\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v,\beta_1u+\beta_2v, \gamma_1u+\gamma_2v\}-2(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v)  \\ \text{subject to} & 0 \le x,y,u,v \le 1
\end{array}$$
Now let's linearize the objective:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} &z_1-2(c_1x+c_2y)+z_2-2(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v)  \\ 
\text{subject to} & 0 \le x,y,u,v \le 1 \\
& \max\{a_1x+a_2y,b_1x+b_2y,c_1x+c_2y\} \geq z_1 \\
& \max\{\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v,\beta_1u+\beta_2v, \gamma_1u+\gamma_2v\} \geq z_2
\end{array}$$
So the question is this: how to handle an inequality of this form:
$$\max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\geq x_4$$
What we do is introduce three binary variables $b_1,b_2,b_3$, and then do this:
$$\begin{gathered}
x_1 + b_1 M \geq x_4, \quad x_2 + b_2 M \geq x_4, \quad x_3 + b_3 M \geq x_4 \\
b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 2, \quad  b_1,b_2,b_3\in\{0,1\}
\end{gathered}$$
where $M$ is a very large number. When $b_i=1$, the term $+b_i M$ makes the inequality trivial to satisfy (assuming $M$ is large enough). The equation $b_1+b_2+b_3=2$ ensures that exactly two of the values of $b_i$ are one. Here are a couple of things I'll leave you to prove to yourself:

- If you use $b_1+b_2+b_3\leq 2$ instead of $b_1+b_2+b_3=2$, this
  transformation will still work.
- If other constraints in the problem
  ensure that $L\leq x_1,x_2,x_3\leq U$, then choosing any $M\geq U-L$
  will be sufficient. In practice, you want $M$ as small as
  possible while ensuring equivalence, so this knowledge helps.

Applying this approach to your problem yields the following model:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} &z_1-2(c_1x+c_2y)+z_2-2(\gamma_1u+\gamma_2v)  \\ 
\text{subject to} & 0 \le x,y,u,v \le 1 \\
& a_1x+a_2y+b_1 M_1 \geq z_1 \\
& b_1x+b_2y+b_2 M_1 \geq z_1 \\
& c_1x+c_2y+b_3 M_1 \geq z_1 \\
& \alpha_1u+\alpha_2v+b_4 M_2 \geq z_2 \\
& \beta_1u+\beta_2v+b_5 M_2 \geq z_2 \\ 
& \gamma_1u+\gamma_2v+b_6 M_2 \geq z_2 \\
& b_1+b_2+b_3\leq 2 \\
& b_4+b_5+b_6\leq 2 \\
& b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6\in\{0,1\}
\end{array}$$
where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are constants that satisfy
$$M_1\geq \max\{a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2,c_1+c_2\}, \quad
M_2\geq \max\{\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\beta_1+\beta_2,\gamma_1+\gamma_2\}.$$

---

When I original read this problem, I mis-read the model as a *minimization*, not a *maximization*. If it is a minimization, then we do not need the binary variables at all; the problem can, in fact, be converted to an LP. I'm providing the equivalent LP here without derivation.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} &z_1 - 2(c_1x+c z_2y) + z_2-2(\gamma_1x+\gamma_2y) 
 \\ \text{subject to} & 0 \le x,y,u,v \le 1 \\
& a_1x+a_2y \leq z_1 \\
& b_1x+b_2y \leq z_1 \\
&  c_1x+c_2y \leq z_1 \\
& \alpha_1u+\alpha_2v \leq z_2 \\
& \beta_1u+\beta_2v \leq z_2 \\
& \gamma_1u+\gamma_2v \leq z_2
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer really help.